# s-nail error: Cannot send email to myself

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu

When I try to send an email via s-nail using this command:

```
echo 'init' | s-nail -s 'init' -Snorecord ubuntu
```

I get this error message:

```
s-nail: $TMPDIR is not a directory or not accessible: /tmp
s-nail: $TMPDIR is not a directory or not accessible: /tmp
s-nail: Panic: Cannot set *TMPDIR* to default value: /tmp
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Does the directory `/tmp` exists and has rwx for all?

Comment: sudo chmod 775 /tmp fixed the issue thanks.

Comment: the command @AchrafJEDAY posted destroyed my s-nail

Answer (score -1):

Changing the ***/tmp*** directory permissions using the following command fixed the issue:

```
sudo chmod 775 /tmp
```